# Changing border color of a textbox

Tags: c#

I want to change a TextBoxes border color after validation fail, but I don't want to do it through the Paint event.

I have a class `Validators`, and methods that validate textboxes.

For example:

```
public bool ValidateDecimalTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    //Validates decimal textboxes.
    //If the textbox is not a decimal value, its bordercolor should turn red.
}
```

I don't know how to do that. help please?

Comment: The are two types: XAML(WPF) and WinForms. Which do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Just place it on a panel that's slightly bigger than the textbox, and set the background color of the textbox.

Comment: See the problem is that this method i have, is used like this:

private bool IsValid()
{
   return Validators.ValidateDecimalTextBoxes(PriceTextBox);
}

And if this method returns false, then the border of that textbox that is given should turn red.

Comment: If it is a winform try to use error provider and make the color change as said above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in **calling**

```
Validators Validate =new Validators();
Validate.ValidateDecimalTextBoxes(textBoxes,this);
```

in your **Validators** class

```
public bool ValidateDecimalTextBoxes(TextBox[] textBoxes,Form v)
 {
     Graphics g =v.CreateGraphics();
      foreach (TextBox txt in textBoxes)
       {
        if (!isdecimal(txt)){
         System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(txt.Location.X, txt.Location.Y+2, 
         txt.ClientSize.Width+4, txt.ClientSize.Height);
          rect.Inflate(1, 3);
          System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g,rect, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
       }
    return true;
  }
```

I suppose that you have create **isdecimal** function